Permission dismissed for navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia in offscreen of Chrome extension
I'm building a Chrome extension that needs to record a tab audio along with user mic.
However, I keep getting the error NotAllowedError: Permission dismissed.
If I check the microphone permissions in the offscreen document (using navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' }), I can see that it's stuck in the prompt state:
{
  name: 'audio_capture',
  state: 'prompt',
  onchange: null
}

The same permission in the foreground (if I run the permissions query in the console) is granted, and the manifest permission array contains tabs, tabCapture, activeTab, offscreen, which should be enough.

My flow is the following:

On the popup page there is a button "start recording" that calls the code below:

const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  target: 'worker',
  type: 'start-recording',
  tabId: tab.id,
});


The service worker receives the message and runs the code below (code from the docs):

const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({});
let recording = false;

const offscreenDocument = existingContexts.find((context) => context.contextType === 'OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT');

if (!offscreenDocument) {
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: 'offscreen.html',
    reasons: ['USER_MEDIA'],
    justification: 'Recording from chrome.tabCapture API',
  });
} else {
  recording = offscreenDocument.documentUrl.endsWith('#recording');
}

if (recording) return

if (tabId) {
  const streamId = await chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({
    targetTabId: tabId,
  });

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'start-recording',
    target: 'offscreen',
    streamId,
  });
}


The offscreen script receives the message with streamId and executes the following:

  const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' }); // state === 'prompt' here
  await audioRecorder.startRecording(streamId);

The code for audioRecorder.startRecording:
try {
  const { combinedStream, audioContext, micGainNode } = await setupAudioCombination(tabStreamId);

  micGainNode.gain.value = 1;

  this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' });
  this.audioContext = audioContext;
  this.micGainNode = micGainNode;

  this.recorder.start(1_000);

  window.location.hash = 'recording';
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

The setupAudioCombination function creates a combined audio stream taking audio from both tab and a mic. The getMicrophoneAudioStream function is the one throwing the permission error:
import { forceUnmutedTabAudio } from './forceUnmutedTabAudio';

export async function setupAudioCombination(tabStreamId: string) {
  const [tabStream, micStream] = await Promise.all([
    getTabAudioStream(tabStreamId),
    getMicrophoneAudioStream(),
  ]);

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();

  const tabSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(tabStream);
  const micSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
  const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
  const micGainNode = audioContext.createGain();

  forceUnmutedTabAudio(tabStream);

  tabSource.connect(destination);
  micSource.connect(micGainNode);
  micGainNode.connect(destination);

  return {
    combinedStream: destination.stream,
    micGainNode,
    audioContext,
  };
}

async function getTabAudioStream(tabStreamId: string) {
  const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {      
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        chromeMediaSourceId: tabStreamId
      }
    },
    video: false,
  });

  return mediaStream;
}

async function getMicrophoneAudioStream() {
  const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false,
  });

  return mediaStream;
}

forceUnmutedTabAudio is a hack I found to avoid auto-muting the user audio when recording starts:
function forceUnmutedTabAudio(tabStream: MediaProvider) {
  const tabAudio = new Audio();
  tabAudio.srcObject = tabStream;
  tabAudio.volume = 1.0;
  tabAudio.play();
}


Could you help me to understand why this is not working, why the mic permission is stuck in the prompt state even though it is granted in the foreground? How do I fix this? What am I missing?


It's a bug in the browser. Try asking for permission in a visible page of your extension. If you're lucky it may work in the popup, but it may fail as it's also bugged, so try opening a new page in a new tab or window.

@woxxom unfortunately, asking for a permission in a popup throws the same error... This is weird because my code used to work previously, like yesterday it was fine, and today it throws the error. Whaat

If the browser updated since yesterday, it's a bug in the new version. Or maybe having devtools open for the offscreen document circumvents the bug.
